# What happens If in a function a variable is declared without var keyword and outside it window.variable is used?

Tags: javascript, scope

FOR EXAMPLE, Let's say

```
setTimeout(  function() {
    variable = setInterval( function() {
        -------------
        -------------
    } , 50);
}, 5000);


clearInterval(window.variable);
```

What happens if var is used

Comment: Without `var`, that initialization creates a global variable.

Comment: Assuming `variable` isn't in scope through some other means such as `let`, `const`, or `with`? Global scope *is* `window.`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)